# How to find the source database name for a field in the result-set in PHP/MySQL API?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to find the database name from where a field is coming.

In MySQL C API, the db name can be retrieved using the API [mysql_fetch_field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-field.html). It returns the [MYSQL_FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-data-structures.html) structure, which contains char *db.

But I am not able to find anything to achieve this. The PHP version of [mysql_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php) does not have the database information. Any idea how can I do this?

I also want a solution for mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you could program a function to do the search- but it would be fairly complex:

First use `mysql_fetch_field` to find the parent table for the field then...

Run the SQL '[SHOW DATABASES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html)' to get a list of databases for the used connection:

```
SHOW {DATABASES | SCHEMAS}
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

Use PHP to loop through each database, for each one run the SQL to [show the underlying tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html):

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name]
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

If the table is found with the same name as provided by `mysql_fetch_field`, as an extra protection against duplicates use [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) to see if it includes the expected field

```
{DESCRIBE | DESC} tbl_name [col_name | wild]
```

If you get a match, you have your DB. Its not fool proof, but it should be fairly robust for most deployments.

Comment: Actually, I need the solution where there are two databases with same table-names.